# geopandas: can't save geojson

Tags: geojson, geopandas

My task is to upload geojson, add data from corresponding csv, drop some columns, then save it back to geojson.

However, after I did everything, added csv data (gj.join(df) ), etc, 
I can't save it to geojson getting this Keyerror:

```
KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()
----> 1 x = newGj.to_json()
2 x

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.pyc in to_json(self, na, *kwargs)
249 return json.dumps(
250 {'type': 'FeatureCollection',
--> 251 'features': [feature(i, row) for i, row in self.iterrows()]},
252 *kwargs )
253

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.pyc in feature(i, row)
245 'properties':
246 dict((k, v) for k, v in iteritems(row) if k != self._geometry_column_name),
--> 247 'geometry': mapping(row[self._geometry_column_name]) }
248 
249 return json.dumps(

KeyError: None
```

Comment: `KeyError` generally means that a key that is being accessed in a dictionary doesn't actually exist. Based on the stack trace, it looks like the internal geometry column name is set to `None`.

Comment: well  I first upload geoDf and it works good - I can parse it to geoJson, etc.
but as soon as I add another dateseries (column) or dataframe (columns), it does not work. however, printing DF shows that geometry column has a correct name 'geometry'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

what commands are you actually using?

**EDIT** lead with misleading/false "no way to 'write to geojson' " comment originally

Looking at the documentation I don't see a way to "write to geojson" other than `geoDF.to_file()` for which you'll get a shapefile or need to specify an [OGR driver](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html).

I like the below option using `geoDF.to_json()` better because it simply returns a GeoJSON formatted string.

Try something like this:

```
with open('test.geojson', 'w') as f:
    f.write(geoDF.to_json())
```

**WARNING**: it looks like `GeoPandas.to_json()` does not specify the CRS so reading back in the data `GeoPandas.read_file()` will assume your data are in WGS (EPSG=4326). I don't see how to specify the crs in the *kwargs* so for me easier to simply reproject the data (`geoDF.to_crs(epsg=4326, inplace=True)`) before writing to file.

Alternatively the below also works for me **BUT**

- it gives me "WARNING:Fiona:CPLE_NotSupported in dataset .geojson does not support layer creation option ENCODING" when I read back in, and
- not all geometries written using the `to_file()` method are equal to gemetries written with the `f.write()` method. I assume this has something to do with how GeoPandas handles the underlying driver but I haven't looked into it further

`nyc_blocks.to_file('geoDF.geojson', driver="GeoJSON")`

Comment: That ENCODING warning also appears in windows, just before crashing python (2.7, 32 bit - Fiona 1.7.0 - GDAL 2.0.3)

Comment: also, it ACTUALLY corrupts encoding

Comment: This worked for me with the caveat that everything was saved as a FeatureCollection.